# How to update part of the state property using Ngrx reducer in Angular 8

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

Here is my initial state. It just adds the name but not under car class as the correct object

```
export const initialState: CustomerState = {
  customer: new Customer(),
};

export class Customer{
id: number;
age: number;
cars: carClass;
phoneNumbers: string[];
}

export class carClass{
name:string;
citiesRegistered:string[];
}
```

Here is my reducer. I am trying to update the state but I am not sure how can I update the nested component of the class

```
export const _customerReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(addNameToCustomerCarRequest , (state, action) => ({
    ...state,
    customer: { ...state.customer, cars: action.name} 
   
  })),

);
```

Here is the action to update just the name of the car class

```
export const addNameToCustomerCarRequest = createAction(
  '[Customer Component] Add Name to customer car request ',
  props<{ name: string }>()
);
```

Comment: You're pretty close, though you didn't give an exact error message you got but I assume the error is due to strongly typed. Since you are only adding the name and its probably yelling at you because you are missing `citiesRegistered` Your reducer on `customer` should look something like this: `customer: { ...state.customer, cars: { ...state.customer.cars, name: action.name }`

Comment: @penleychan How can I initialize the object to be empty because I am getting undefined errors when I am trying to get the state of citiesRegistered because cars is undefined.
Can you check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66145715/initialize-the-initial-state-object-to-be-an-empty-object-instead-of-undefined

Comment: easy way is to initialize default values it on your `Customer` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
export const _customerReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(addNameToCustomerCarRequest , (state, action) => ({
    ...state,
    customer: { ...state.customer, cars: { ...state.cars, name: action.name } } 
   
  })),

);

This is the new syntax and I am not familiar with it. It should either be `action.payload.name` or `action.name`.
```

Comment: It does not work. It says Property 'cars' does not exist on type 'CustomerState'.
Red line on ...state.cars